# what is current latest runtime version of Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-function-app-proxy, azure-functions-core-tools

is Azure Fucntion runtime 2.0 released now ? or it is still under preview ? What it is going to be realsed please ?

I coulnd't figure it out. Few MS documents say it is preview and some of the are saying it is alpha released ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

[Azure Function 2.0](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-azure-functions-2-0/) has been generally available.

---

The short answer is runtime 2.x is still preview. We can use it in development but not for production. As you may have seen in [Azure Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions).

You may have seen Alpha release in [Azure function host](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases). It is marked as pre-release.

And also you can see `Runtime version: 2.0.11651.0 (beta)` in Azure portal.

Both of them means runtime 2.x is still preview and will become GA later.

In terms of deprecation, 1.x will continue to exist for a considerable amount of time after 2.x becomes GA. See [GitHub issue reply](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/640#issuecomment-356139083).